# How to install tensorflow on m1 mac using pipenv

Tags: tensorflow, apple-m1, pipenv, apple-silicon

In our project we use pipenv and I can't switch everyone on conda.
I'm using python 3.9 and pipenv. I tried to install pipenv inside conda env, but it didn't work well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure you have Xcode Command Line Tools installed by executing `xcode-select -p`.

Install HDF5 library using Homebrew and h5py without binaries.

```
brew install hdf5
export HDF5_DIR="$(brew --prefix hdf5)"
export PIP_NO_BINARY=h5py && pipenv install h5py
```

Install TF

```
pipenv install tensorflow-macos
pipenv install tensorflow-metal
```

Skip *tensorflow-deps* and install any missing libraries manually. You can find some more details in [this blog post](https://bumpyroad.hashnode.dev/tensorflow-on-apple-silicon-with-pipenv).